# How to increment build number in file using sed/grep?

Tags: regex, sed, grep, versioning

I have file

version.h

```
#define BUILD_NO T("0124")
#define MILESTONE ALPHA
```

Assume that I set proper MILESTONE as system variable

I want to increase build number only if new MILESTONE variable (ALPHA, BETA, RC, GOLDEN) is this same like in file, otherwise I want to update only MILESTONE.

How can I do that using sed/grep ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inc() {
    : ${MILESTONE:?set env var first}
    local fname=${1:?file name is empty}

    if egrep -q "^#define\s+MILESTONE\s+$MILESTONE" "$fname"
    then
        gawk '/^#define BUILD_NO/{sub(/[0-9]+/, sprintf("%04d", gensub("[^0-9]", "", "g", $3)+1))}1' "$fname"
    else
        sed -r "/^(#define MILESTONE).*/s//\\1 $MILESTONE/" "$fname"
    fi
}
```

#### TEST

```
$ MILESTONE=ALPHA
$ inc version.h
#define BUILD_NO T("0125")
#define MILESTONE ALPHA

$ MILESTONE=BETA
$ inc version.h
#define BUILD_NO T("0124")
#define MILESTONE BETA
```

Comment: `gensub` is a non-standard extension so maybe `gawk` instead of `awk`.

Comment: @Arkku: how this should look like with `gawk`?

Comment: I don't know why, however incrementing number doesn't work on my machine. I forgot mentioned that I used cygwin. I have gawk 3.1.7. Should I enable gawk extension in same way?

Comment: my awk version is `GNU Awk 3.1.8`

Comment: @noisy for simplicity, I didn't add `[[:space:]]+` to the `awk` pattern. Please check these only one `whitespace` between `#define` and `BUILD_NO`.

Comment: it seams that is something wrong with `if egrep -q "^#define\s+MILESTONE\s+$MILESTONE" "$fname"`, it always return false